# How to use a dynamic parameter with a command in crystal reports?

Tags: dynamic, crystal-reports, command

The problem I'm running into is quite easy to recreate.

In Crystal Reports Developer I add two different tables:

- The full table "Users"
- A Command containing SELECT * FROM Users

In the Field Explorer I add a new parameter and set this to dynamic. I have this parameter pull it's data from any field in either of the two tables (doesn't matter). Of course making sure the parameter is used in the record select.

If I now preview this report (in Developer) it works perfectly. I get a popup allowing me to select data from whatever field I selected in the parameter.

Using this report in Crystal Viewer it prompts for database username and password.

It seems it only does this when the same report contains both a dynamic parameter and a command. Removing the SQL command (leaving only the table) and the report works as expected.

Does anyone know how to resolve this, or is there some workaround?